# How to add id to optgroup using blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

Using blade in laravel select can be done like

```
{!! Form::select('animal', array(
'Cats' => array('leopard' => 'Leopard'),
'Dogs' => array('spaniel' => 'Spaniel'),
)) !!}
```

At the screen this looks like this

[image]

HTML for this looks like

```
<select name="animal">
  <optgroup label="Cats">
    <option value="leopard">
      Leopard
    </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Dogs">
    <option value="spaniel">
      Spaniel
    </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

And that is fine, but i need that each optgroup has unique "value" so i wish to use `id` so each `optrgroup` has different `id`. So it should look like this

```
<select name="animal">
  <optgroup label="Cats" id="1">
    <option value="leopard">
      Leopard
    </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Dogs" id="2">
    <option value="spaniel">
      Spaniel
    </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Is this possible to do it with blade and how?

I would like to have just

```
{!! Form:select('animal', $data) !!}
```

Comment: There is no default method to do it. However, you can achieve that by some changes. Check this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-way-to-overwrite-option-method-from-laravel-5-formbuilder-class)

Comment: Why are you need the 'id'? Can you instead use the value attrib of a option tag? e.g. 'value="1"'?

Comment: Regards of that id i have some changes for that particular id which represents the primary key of table company in my database. So when user changes the option group he also receives change of some data/pictures on screen.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could replace the Form::select to something like this :

```
<select name="animal">
  @forearch($data as $animal)
    <optgroup id="{{ $animal->categoryid }}" label="{{ $animal->category }}">
     <option value="{{ $animal->type }}">
      {{ $animal->type }}
     </option>
    </optgroup>
  @endforeach
 </select>
```

Yours sincerely,
Flm

Comment: I know how to do it using `@foreach` but the part of my question which apparently you missed was "Is this possible to do it with blade and how?". So my desired solution would be using blade `{!! Form:select(') !!}`